# New instance in a cronjob php

Tags: php, cron

I want to execute a periodic task using a php script.

Inside my script (into my cron job), I am trying to instantiate a class without success:

The include works fine:

`include_once (dirname(__FILE__).\'../my/class/MyObjectMgrClass.php\');`

But as soon as I try to instantiate the class, the cron does not work anymore:

```
$myObjectMgr = new MyObjectMgr();
```

Comment: What error does it give?

Comment: Why are you adding those escape characters try this assuming thats the correct path `include_once dirname(__FILE__) . '../my/class/MyObjectMgrClass.php';` Also you dont need the `()` it works but is not the way you are supposed to use include/require

Answer (score 1):

"include_once()" try to include the file you define but won't stop the script if it doesn't exists
Try to use require_once(), it will trigger a fatal error if the file is missing.
by the way when your concatenate with dirname, add and / to the begin of the string like

```
 require_once (dirname(__FILE__)). '/../my/class/MyObjectMgrClass.php';
```

Also don't use the \ unless you want to escape something.

Comment: ok thanks, sorry the escape character were not in the include statement: misstyping... but, true the error was the last bracket: include_once (dirname(__FILE__).'../my/class/MyObjectMgrClass.php'); which was wrong. thanks a lot!